right way of saving userID after logging in using shared preferences in flutter
i am creating a login system,i have declaired global variable uid & nameOfUser in main.dart file, just after import lines are done.(before void main )
i am using sharedpreference to store and then checking if uid is saved, so that user should be logged in, and doesn't need to login every time.
is this the right way ? or someone can hack app?
ps. is there way to store data (like shared pref ) in getx state manager?
void auth() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    try {
      var authResponse = await _dio.post(
        '/app_api/login.php',
        data: {
          "mobile": _phoneController.text,
          "pass": _passController.text,
        },
        options: Options(
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        ),
      );

      var responseData = authResponse.data;

      if (responseData['status'] == true) {
        setState(() {
          uID = responseData['UID'];
          nameOfUser = responseData['Name'];
        });
        await prefs.setString('uID', '${responseData['UID']}');
        await prefs.setString('nameOfUser', '${responseData['Name']}');
        Get.offAll(() => const HomeScreen());
      } else {
        _passController.clear();
        Get.snackbar(
          'Login Failed',
          'Please enter correct mobile number and password',
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          colorText: Colors.white,
        );
      }
    } catch (e) {
      Get.snackbar(
        'Error',
        'An error occurred during login: $e',
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        colorText: Colors.white,
      );
    }
  }


Yes, this is the right way to store the user ID and name of the User. An alternative of shared preference is secure storage where you can store data in an encrypted format.

You can user GetStorage package also. It is also a good option
